# How to specify the listening server instances using cherrypy tree.mount?

Tags: python, cherrypy

Let us create an application server and an admin server. Assume that `fusionListener` and `adminListener` contain the application and admin logic we want to expose.

```
  from cherrypy._cpserver import Server
  fserver = Server()
  fserver.socket_port = 10000
  fserver.subscribe()

  aserver = Server()
  aserver.socket_port = 10001
  aserver.subscribe()
```

And then to start them:

```
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

The `tree.mount` parameters ask for:

- the code/ business logic as the first parameter
- listening url
- config parameters

Here is how that looks for the above servers:

```
  cherrypy.tree.mount(fusionListener, r"/fusion.*",fusionConf)
  cherrypy.tree.mount(adminListener, r"/admin.*",adminConf)
```

But where is the parameter for the *server* itself - which includes the *port* being listened to?

Comment: https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/deploy.html#virtual-hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a well supported case for CherryPy.

The application selection (`cherrypy.tree` is basically a map of /path -> App) is done before the request dispatch and... long story short, you *could* use `cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost` and map you sub applications under a main one (that will route depending on the hostname (which the port can be part of). For the listening on multiple ports, can be done, but again this is a very custom arrangement.

I hope this example is illustrative of a possible way to make such *feat*:

```
import cherrypy

from cherrypy import dispatch
from cherrypy._cpserver import Server


class AppOne:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def default(self):
        return "DEFAULT from app ONE!"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def foo(self):
        return "FOO from app ONE"


class AppTwo:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def default(self):
        return "DEFAULT from app TWO!"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def foo(self):
        return "FOO from app TWO"


class Root:

    def __init__(self):
        self.one = AppOne()
        self.two = AppTwo()


def bind_two_servers(app_one_port, app_two_port):
    # unsubscribe the default server
    cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()
    s1 = Server()
    s2 = Server()
    s1.socket_port = app_one_port
    s2.socket_port = app_two_port
    # subscribe the server to the `cherrypy.engine` bus events
    s1.subscribe()
    s2.subscribe()


def start_server():
    bind_two_servers(8081, 8082)
    cherrypy.engine.signals.subscribe()
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()


config = {
    '/': {
        'request.dispatch': dispatch.VirtualHost(**{
            'localhost:8081': '/one',
            'localhost:8082': '/two',
        })
    }
}

cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/', config)
start_server()
```

This example will serve `AppOne` when coming from `localhost:8081` and `AppTwo` when coming from `localhost:8082`.

The problem is that you can't do multiples `cherrypy.tree.mount` and expect to route into the different applications using the `VirtualHost` dispatcher, it assumes that the application resolution is done at that point and is only resolving the path of that application.

Having said all of that... I do not recommend this solution, it can get complicated and it would be better to have some other server in front (like nginx) and serve each path on different processes. This could be an alternative, only if you really *really* want to avoid any extra server or process in your setup.

Comment: Wlll this work if bound to something other than `localhost` ?  e.g. 192.168.0.18  or 127.0.0.1  or myHostName ?

Comment: Yes. The dispatch is done based on the request Host header.