# Is it possible to create a Tornado application from instances of Request/Web Handlers instead of class definitions?

Tags: python, tornado

The apparent requirement to provide `class` definitions instead of instances causes very difficult problems.  I have two different classes and one of them needs a reference to the other

```
  app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/fusion.*", FusionListener),
    (r"/admin.*", AdminListener),
  ])
```

.  The `AdminListener` needs a reference to the FusionListener since there are internal items needing to be managed. Sending messages is an unacceptable additional complexity here.  The current mechanism does not seem to afford that possibility.

What kind of pattern can get around this shortcoming in Tornado?

Comment: What internal items do you need to manage?

Comment: "internal items" : current scenario state including state of inventory and personnel . `admin` can `reset` that state and make other modifications

Comment: I do not actually want the `web.Application` to control my entire app: i would prefer to start it off in its own area and not hijack the main processing thread.  I'll look to see if there were examples of that. This is completely busting my backend server design.

Comment: If it's state that needs to be managed wouldn't that belong in a `cache` or `persistence` layer? It can be something as simple as a global object, a dedicated cache server or a full-blown database.

Comment: There is both persistent and in-memory state. The latter wants to live in a class managing the state: but I am compelled to significantly redraw the boundaries due to this design ot `tornado`. Instead I am now needing to push everything to global variables.  I will be dumping `tornado` as soon as I can get the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use-case there are both persistent and in-memory state. We have `spark` and `postgres` repositories for the former. For the latter I had already designed and written the application to have instance-level data structures.  But I have gathered that instance attributes on `Tornado` launched `RequestHandler` / `WebHandler` subclasses are not persistent.

The latter wants to live in a class managing the state: but I am compelled to significantly redraw the boundaries due to this design ot `Tornado`. Instead it will be necessary to push everything to global variables.  Few would argue this were a preferred design.  I will be dumping `tornado` as soon as I can get the time.

Not sure what will be the alternative:  I already reverted from `cherrypy` due to significant limitations of its own: here are a couple of my questions on it

- [404 for path served by Cherrypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841848/404-for-path-served-by-cherrypy)
- [How to specify the listening server instances using cherrypy tree.mount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838587/how-to-specify-the-listening-server-instances-using-cherrypy-tree-mount)

I got through those with some scars but still in one piece. There were additional issues that knocked me out: `url's` were not being served, and there was no clear end to the mole whacking.   It also generally does not get a lot of attention and has confusing outdated or incomplete documentation. There is *plenty* of docs - that's why I got started on it: but the holes make for a series of rabbit-chasing episodes.

`Flask` and `django` have their own issues.  It seems finding a functionally  adequate but not super heavy weight web server in `python` is an illusory target. Not certain yet which framework has the least gotchas.

Comment: What about using class attributes for RequestHandler? These will be persisted between requests and shared among instances.

Comment: @IonutTicus   I  had tried to use class attributes with `tornado` earlier but was unsuccessful to see the values persisting: they seemed to be transient - against my understanding of how class variables should work.  It may well be I did not use them properly.  I can try again. What would really help: if you have some pointer to an example using class attributes with tornado that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as answer in order to benefit from proper code formatting.
The paradigm I used for keeping track of existing instances of a RequestHandler is very simple:

```py
class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    _instances = set()

    def get(self):
        if needs_to_be_added(self.request):  # some conditions can be used here
            if len(MyHandler._instances) > THRESHOLD:  # careful with memory usage
                return self.finish("some_error")
            MyHandler._instances.add(self)
        ...

    def post(self):
        if needs_to_be_removed(self.request):
            MyHandler._instances.discard(self)
        ...
```

Of course you might need to change when to add / discard elements.
Depending on how you want to refer to existing instances in the future (by some key for example) you could use a `dict` for keeping track of them.

I don't think you can use something weak references (as in classes from the [weakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) module) because those will only track **live** instances which won't work with the way request handlers instances are created and destroyed.